# Finding an eigenvector from its corresponding eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Greetings dear comunity of math.stackexchange.

I am new to the site and it has helped me a lot by the way, you guys make an awesome job. My question is very simple, it is about eigenvalues, I have been studying for a while but feel free to make any suggestions and comments.

The thing is that to find eigenvalues we can find them with the QR method (whether they are real of complex) for mid size matrices. For Larger matrices we can approximate the largest one of them with the Arnoldi iteration, however I only know how to use these methods to find eigenvalues, but I don't know any method to find the eigenvectors (specially complex eigenvectors). One idea that came to mind was to use the power method (with an initial complex seed vector) with the Wieldants deflation several times in order to find the largest eigenvectors and there corresponding eigenvalues, but I don't know if there is a better way.

In conclusion, my question is: if I have a matrix and all of its eigenvalues, how can I find (efficiently) the eigenvectors (whether they are real or complex)?

Comment: Pretty much any iterative method that I can think of finds the two simultaneously. But if you actually do have all the eigenvalues, you are probably best off trying an eigenvector method that permits shifting.

Comment: Would you explain them to me please? or at least how does the QR method compute the eigenvectors?

Comment: similar question and answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258847/solved-how-to-retrieve-eigenvectors-from-qr-algorithm-that-applies-shifts-and-d?newreg=fbbe92830e5741eb9913f56c551494b7